# How to make the Ninja Form Fields Required on clicking a checkbox?

Tags: wordpress, validation, ninja-forms

I am using Ninja form and I have a checkbox field. On click of this checkbox I have two input fields which are displayed. I have to make both the fields as required. How can I make both of them required?

I've used jQuery to add required property but when I click on submit the form is submitted without showing any errors.

I
                        Know a Employee 
                
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                
                
            
        
    


    
        
            
            
        
        
            
                Employee Full name
                    
                
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                
                
            
        
    


    
        
            
            
        
        
            
                Employee Email

I used the conditional logic extension for showing and hiding the two input fields on checking and unchecking of the Checkbox. Also, Used jQuery for acheiving the same functionality. Expected output, On checking the checkbox, Both the fields should be visible and required before submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

Scrap the extra jQuery, just simply make the fields required using the 
[provided toggle option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj1yd.png)

Then setup the conditional logic so that the fields are hidden when they're not checked and vice versa. When the fields are hidden it will act as if they don't exist, meaning you will not be required to fill out the hidden required fields to submit. But when the box is checked and they show again you will have to fill out the fields. If this doesn't work try updating your conditional logic add-on, as I don't think it always worked like this.